# How to revert all downvotes given in the past?

Tags: support, voting

I have come to the conclusion that downvotes are negative, punishing, impolite, destructive and destroying.

I want to support a positive, constructive, nourishing and uplifting atmosphere.

Therefore, I want to undo all the downvotes that I have cast in the past. However, this is only possible for posts which have been edited. Is there a way to revert downvotes?

Comment: You can't. You can't undo a vote if the post isn't edited, simple as that.

Comment: @Patrice Can I edit the posts myself ?

Comment: Unless you have 2000 rep the edit will need to be reviewed, also downvotes are good and important for the site when used properly.

Comment: at 703 rep, your edits need to be checked and reviewed by people. If there's something to edit on the post, have fun. Don't just edit to let you undownvote. And as Joe is pointing out, DVs are important to keep the site its quality...

Comment: So, indicating to others that a post is no good is a bad thing?

Comment: If you want to be more positive, constructive, nourishing and uplifting you can do much better things: Put bounties on good answers/questions you see. (And please continue to downvote where appropriate).

Comment: @Deduplicator Of course it is. The world is a much better place when everyone is told to use information that doesn't work, is unclear, is dangerous or actively harmful when used, etc.  When people are only directed to useful content that works, is clear, isn't dangerous or harmful to use, etc. they end up being far less happy users.

Comment: Please don't give up on down votes - they're a really important signal to both the system as a whole and the OP. They let us hide dangerously wrong information in a way that comments alone can't and they make it clear that this is not just another forum to dump terrible questions on.

Comment: @Deduplicator Not via downvotes. There are much better ways. I have written this in my manifesto (aka *Profile*).

Comment: @false I am nourishing, not destroying. I see you need it, therefore, you get an **upvote** ...

Comment: That's a horribly misguided manifesto you've written there. I will readily assume you're honestly trying to improve the site. But this is not the way.

Comment: @SQLPolice HOW? you want the handful of experienced users who care about quality to go and comment to help all the help vamps who post anything on this site? Your idea, while honestly praiseworthy, doesn't scale to Stack Overflow's size...

Comment: I mean, we could just have all questions automagically start out at -10, and then remove downvotes. though, i feel that would look far more negative to new users.

Comment: @SQLPolice: Thanks! But so far you offered 0 bounties, that's a number which is next-to-negative!

Comment: @Patrice I am convinced of positive pedagogic. In my ideal world, I want that all users take their daily budget of 40 upvotes and spread them the best posts they find. Then the best posts would bubble up automagically, and the bad keep down.

Comment: @SQLPolice unfortunately, people upvote bad posts too, so that won't work.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, the idea with starting at -10 and only going upwards is interesting. In fact, that correlates with my thinking.

Comment: @SQLPolice and those who post crap questions would never be throttled, stopped, or whatever. The roomba would never clean anything.... I am with the positive pedagogy, but in a site with the size of Stack, it's simply not viable

Comment: The ideal world doesn't exist. The fact of the matter is that bad and possibly dangerous answers are posted all the time, just like bad questions are posted all the time. The only tool you have to help these people *is* to downvote, otherwise you're teaching them that it is good even if you don't vote at all.

Comment: @SQLPolice: Starting with -10 is even more intimidating. Look how many never ask a question.

Comment: starting at -10, and not receiving rep unless it gets above 0 for example, would mean the majority of questions/answers result in no gain of rep

Comment: You clearly need to read [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/) (Jeff Atwood on downvoting)

Comment: Apparently, I've downvoted over 25000 times (not including posts that have been deleted), and I can safely say:  each one of those downvotes was warranted.  There is an absolute surplus of crap questions (and to a much lesser extent, answers) on this site.

Comment: See [Removing the downvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259543) and also the questions that random has linked from there.

Comment: This would be a simple support question (which Servy has answered) without the rainbow-dust _Weltanshauung_ bits. Unfortunately, it's gone completely off the rails because of that. I'd like to edit, but I fear it's far too late.

Comment: as someone who mostly downvotes on SO, I can say that this is nonsense - downvotes help separate the crap from the reasonable and the good.  Your post here and your 'manifesto' do not convince me otherwise.

Comment: @santiago Focussing on downvoting is like using all energy to build a massive wall with all kind of security gadgets around your house. Eventually your house will be top-secure, but there will be no life inside.

Comment: George Carlin: *In today's America, no child ever loses. There are no losers anymore. Everyone's a winner. No matter what the game or sport or competition, everybody wins. Everybody wins, everybody gets a trophy, no one is a loser. No child these days ever gets to hear those all-important, character building words: **"You lost, Bobby!"***

Answer (score 36):

Nope, there is no way and you shouldn't be doing it to begin with. Downvotes aren't negative. Downvotes separate the good from the bad.

If anything we need more downvotes, because we really don't hand out all that many. So please reconsider even for those where you can revert your votes. If it's bad, it's bad.

Comment: -1 because you told me to downvote more.

Comment: YOU UNDO THAT RIGHT NOW!!!

Comment: All these mixed signals.  Just make up your mind already.

Comment: @Servy You need nourishment, I upvoted you.

Comment: Consider a world without downvotes. Only novotes or upvotes. I gave you an upvote so you can feel it better.

Comment: So you're voting to make me happy? Then you're doing it wrong and as a bonus you have annoyed me. You're trying to create some voting utopia which in reality is actively harmful.

Comment: @SQLPolice If you're upvoting content purely to make the user happy (or, as appears to actually be the case, because it makes *you* happy) , rather than based on (your opinion of) the quality of the post in question, then you're *actively harming* the community.  Don't do that.  Use votes to indicate the quality of posts, not to make people feel better regardless of the content of the post.  Think of every other person who will later read the post in question (which is who votes are *actually* for).  Vote for *their* sake, rather than just doing what makes you feel good.

Comment: @SQLPolice I have considered that world, and it's awful.

Comment: @Servy I make people happy **only** when they provide somehing useful, of course. Here at Meta, I just showed you the effect.

Comment: @SQLPolice who have you made happy in this post?

Comment: @Bart I did here only to show you the effect. At stackoverflow, I focus on **quality** postings. These get my attention and upvotes. Bad posts get no vote or a comment.

Comment: Don't vote to show me any effect. Vote up because you think it's a great contribution. Voted down because you find it's not. It't a simple mechanism and one of the few things we have to keep quality in check and to clearly signal to others how they should value some of the content. If you go against that, you're actively harming the site. I can't stop you, but would seriously ask you reconsider. You can abstain from voting, but don't change your already cast downvotes unless the value of the posts changed.

Comment: To give you a simple example: if more people were like you and someone who posted a constant stream of crap would never receive downvotes, then the ban doesn't kick in. You may not have harmed their feelings, but you've made the site actively worse for all visitors. So while you sit there feeling all warm and fuzzy and positive, we have to find another way to deal with the crap that caused.

Comment: @Bart As said, I did here only because it's meta, this is like a playground here. At SO, I don't make people "happy", but I want to *nourish* quality posts, and the effort some people do. I read a lot through psots, and I see a lot very good psots. All those get upvotes. Why would you like to stop that.

Comment: We don't want to stop people from upvoting quality posts. We want to encourage that. What we do not want to encourage is not downvoting poor quality posts.

Comment: Ugh, that word "nourish" is driving me crazy for some reason.  Seriously, it  makes me feel queasy.  Wonder what that's about.

Comment: Makes me hungry @LittleBobbyTables.

Comment: @Bart If more people would be like me, than possibly the atmosphere would be even more positive ;) And the crap-generator would possibly feel lonely because he gets no attention. So he would need to make an effort, which is equal to post quality.

Comment: @SQLPolice Your point of view would be good, if only there were no rep whores who will ANSWER the "crap generators" anyway

Comment: If more people were like you, this site would be full of useless junk, and would be completely useless (and dangerous) to all viewers

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables That's interesting, possibly that's because you are starving ;)  Or you think I'm jesus or spiritual or something. But I'm atheist. I just came to the conclusion that the world is a better place when we encourage the positive.

Comment: @TinyGiant How could that be possible. If more people were like me, than there would be clearly more quality posts. At least at stackoverflow ;)

Comment: No, there would be no more quality posts than there already is, what there would be is a very large amount of crap not being disposed of.

Comment: @SQLPolice but the spam, crap, virus, dangerous answers (SQL injection, bad practices, etc) would STAY... at 0, granted, but would STAY.

Comment: @SQLPolice More upvotes doesn't make for a more positive atmosphere.  On other q/a sites I've been active on in the past that had no equivalent to a downvote were just *filled* with crap and drivel, making it a completely *miserable* atmosphere as there was just so much crap content, and what quality content existed couldn't distinguish itself.  SO's success is largely a result of the extensive effort it has done to discourage/remove low quality content.  It's why it makes so many people so happy when they're able to use the site and easily find quality content.

Comment: @Patrice There's *lots* of crap posts that have more than 0 upvotes.  Fortunately many of those posts have even more downvotes, so it's still clear to readers that they're of low quality, but the idea that people don't upvote crap is just false.

Comment: @Servy Makes my point even more :p If the crap content gets upvoted by people who have no idea what they're doing.... then if we remove downvotes as SQLPolice seems to want to do, then crap content won't even be at 0...

Comment: @Patrice Well, that's a point, of course there is crap, spam and even harmful and malicious content. But how about **flagging** such posts ?

Comment: @SQLPolice You have 6 helpful flags, I have 900+... don't worry, I flag. DV are just another tool. Crap doesn't NECESSARILY warrant a flag. If it's just horribly formatted, not answering the right question, etc etc, I think a flag is too bad... and too "punitive" (to use your own words).

Comment: @SQLPolice you want to stop downvoting? Fair enough. But there's no point trying to talk others into it, and you can't undo what you've already done.

Comment: Who handles flags, @SQLPolice? The moderators. We have a dozen of those. There's tens of thousands of people who can vote up and down. When a mod is presented with a post that you have flagged "this is not the correct answer", and she doesn't know the language it's in, what is she supposed to do? Flagging for "wrong" doesn't scale up.

Answer (score 18):

Since no one else seems to have suggested it, there is *one* way to remove all of your down votes.

You could delete your account. This would effectively nullify all your votes.

Comment: well, it wouldn't nullify the votes, it would just make them not yours, unless i misunderstand how that process works.

Comment: @KevinB No, it is really right: If a user is deleted, then all his downvotes are given back. So if a grumpy cat is deleted, then a lot of other users will see "green lights" popping up ;)

Comment: That's indeed true, however, not an option to me. I'm not self-destructive ;)

Comment: @Trobbins had to look that up: *basically a goober is just a kindhearted, rather oblivious goofball.* Haha, LOL!! But that's not the case. I can distinguish between quality and crap, but I want to shift towards quality.

Comment: @SQLPolice So what about all of the other people reading those posts that *can't* distinguish between the quality and the crap posts?  Do you want to prevent those people from realizing what answers are crap, and to benefit from your expertise, by providing that feedback in the appropriate manor (a downvote)?

Comment: @KevinB: all votes will be removed with the account. Sometimes an exception is made (when a user with a *lot* of votes wants their account deleted it would be too disruptive, so for special cases the votes are transferred to the Community User).

Comment: @MartijnPieters regarding that exceptional case I would add that if they remove downvotes of a very active user, there is a risk of compromising voting anonymity (this happened [at MSE when Mark Trapp left](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156507/165773)). So they have to keep all the votes, up and down, they only transfer these to Community user

Answer (score 12):

No, there is no way to do that.